# Is there any way we can perform soft delete in JPA when Entity class is using @Version?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

When I am trying to perform Soft delete on my Entity, I am getting below error:

> org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not delete: [study.study.entity.Student#e4a860d5-8dd0-4abe-b218-76672627e6b0]; SQL [update student set is_deleted=true where student_id=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not delete: [study.study.entity.Student#e4a860d5-8dd0-4abe-b218-76672627e6b0]\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException

Here is my Entity class:

```java
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@SQLDelete(sql="update student set is_deleted=true where student_id=?")
public class Student {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    private String studentId;

    @Column(nullable = false,columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "age")
    private Integer age;

    @Version
    private Integer version;

    private boolean isDeleted;
}
```

and here is my service method

```java
@Transactional
    public String deleteSt(String id) {
        sr.deleteById(id);
        return "Deleted";
    }
```

*I am thinking as I am updating(not actually deleting) student entity by using native SQL query so native SQL query is unable to update version field and therefore JPA is throwing error.*
**If it is so, then what are the ways we can handle this situation?**

**EDIT 1:**

We can achieve deletion lie this : `@SQLDelete(sql="update student set is_deleted=true where student_id=? and version=?")`. **But now the question is, this way we are not updating the version field value and if any other program rely on version field for performing updation at their end then it will miss the update because version field is not updated.**

Comment: The way I read the documentation of `SQLDelete`, your SQL statement should have two parameters: the first one for the id, the second one for the version.

Comment: @Code It will be nice if you could provide the link of the documentation because i can't find it in official Hibernate documentation.

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/SQLDelete.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because you are trying to perform a soft delete on your entity using a native SQL query, which prevents Hibernate from properly handling entity version and optimistic locking. To fix this, you need to implement soft delete correctly using JPA without resorting to native SQL queries. You can achieve this by tuning your code to update the entity's isDeleted property and let Hibernate take care of updating the version automatically. Also, consider adding a @Where clause to your entity to automatically exclude soft-deleted records from regular queries. With these changes, you will be able to perform soft deletes on your Student entity without version issues.

Here is a version of your code with these fixes:

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Where(clause = "is_deleted = false")
public class Student {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    private String studentId;

    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "age")
    private Integer age;

    @Version
    private Integer version;

    private boolean isDeleted;
}

@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, String> {
}

@Service
@Transactional
public class StudentService {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    public String deleteStudent(String id) {
        Optional<Student> optionalStudent = studentRepository.findById(id);
        if (optionalStudent.isPresent()) {
            Student student = optionalStudent.get();
            student.setDeleted(true);
            studentRepository.save(student);
            return "Student removed";
        } else {
            return "Student not found";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach is fine when there is no Parent Child relationship but what if our Student entity is parent and we want to delete Student entity whenever our Child entity is deleted. Basically by using ``cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE`` in my Child entity.

Comment: Let's say you have a student entity as a parent and a child entity as a child, and you want to implement a soft delete on both entities. This is how you can achieve this (even just the affected parameters):

Student entity:
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
     private List<Child> children;

child entity:
     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name = "student_id")
     private Student student;

In your service class, the deleteSt method remains the same.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, you are performing update in service class then how will it make sure to perform the updation when Child entity is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

AS you can read on the article bellow. The solution is quite simple when wanting to implement a soft delete mechanism when also using the JPA feature of `@Version`

```java
@Entity(name = "Example")
@Table(name = "example")
@SQLDelete(sql = """
UPDATE example
SET deleted = true
WHERE
    id = ? AND
    version = ?
""")
@Loader(namedQuery = "findExampleById")
@NamedQuery(name = "findExampleById", query = """
select e
from Example e
where
    e.id = ?1 and
    e.deleted = false
""")
@Where(clause = "deleted = false")
public class Example extends SoftDeletable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NaturalId
    private String name;

    @Version
    private short version;
}
```

`SoftDeletable` also looks like:

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class SoftDeletable {
    private boolean deleted;
}
```

Now whenever you try to delete an entity, hibernate will execute the `@SQLDelete` and set the deleted to true.

Also when trying to load an entity, the `@Where` clause will be applied filtering out soft deleted entities

More details and examples can be found on this article: [*Soft delete and JPA version property*](https://vladmihalcea.com/soft-delete-jpa-version/)

Comment: Please add all clarification to your answer instead of posting links to external ressources

Comment: A clarification of what? The article is explanatory with examples and implementation details. I do not want to copy paste things here. That's the reason I tagged the author as well!

Comment: Answers should not solely contain of a link to an external ressources

Comment: Anyway, I added an example and some explanation on this.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible to perform a soft delete in JPA (Java Persistence API) while using a `Version` field in the entity class. Soft delete refers to marking an entity as deleted without physically removing it from the database. Instead of deleting the record permanently, you update a special flag or field to indicate that the entity has been "soft deleted."

The `Version` field in JPA is typically used for optimistic locking, which helps avoid data conflicts in concurrent environments. However, you can also leverage this field for soft delete purposes, depending on your specific use case.

Here's how you can achieve soft delete using JPA and the `Version` field:

1. Add a `@Version` annotation to the field that you want to use for optimistic locking. For example:

```java
@Entity
public class YourEntity {
    // Other entity fields

    @Version
    private Long version;

    // Getter and setter methods
}
```

2. Introduce a new field to indicate whether the entity has been deleted, along with getter and setter methods:

```java
@Entity
public class YourEntity {
    // Other entity fields

    @Version
    private Long version;

    private boolean deleted;

    // Getter and setter methods for 'deleted'
    public boolean isDeleted() {
        return deleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted(boolean deleted) {
        this.deleted = deleted;
    }
}
```

3. When you want to perform a soft delete, instead of removing the entity, set the `deleted` field to `true` and update the entity using the JPA EntityManager:

```java
YourEntity entity = entityManager.find(YourEntity.class, entityId);
entity.setDeleted(true);
entityManager.merge(entity); // Use merge() to update the entity.
```

4. Make sure to handle soft-deleted entities appropriately in your application logic to exclude them from regular queries if needed.

By using this approach, you can maintain a "soft-deleted" state for your entities while still utilizing the `Version` field for optimistic locking purposes. Remember to consider the implications of soft deletes on your application's behavior, including how to handle queries, cascading operations, and potential data retention policies.

Comment: I know we can achieve this using EntityManager but what if we use @SQLDelete annotation for performing update? How can we achieve it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Ahmad Aftab.

Your answer appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). A heads-up that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

We do hope you'll be a part of our community and contribute with *your own*, quality posts in the future. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.